# retrieve the value of all children from an xml node then apply a javascript function to each

Tags: javascript, xml

If i change the xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<events>
<event>
    <date>
        <weekday>ven</weekday>
        <day>15</day>
        <month>feb</month>
    </date>
    <place>
        <name>Blue Sound</name>
        <city>Nola</city>
        <address>Corso Italia 7</address>
    </place>
    <band>
        <name>Random Jazz 6some</name>
        <link>http://randomjazz6.ran</link>
        <members>
            <drummer> Random Drummer </drummer>
            <vocal> Random Vocalist </vocal>
            <bass>Random Bassist</bass>
            <guitar>Random Guitar</guitar>
            <keys>Random keyboarder</keys>
            <other>Random otherist</other>
        </members>
    </band>
    <description>this is the event number 1, ven 15 feb</description>
</event>
<event>
    <date>
        <weekday>ven</weekday>
        <day>1</day>
        <month>mar</month>
    </date>
    <place>
        <name>Dada</name>
        <city>Chicago</city>
        <address>Random Street 7</address>
    </place>
    <band>
        <name>Random Jazz band 2</name>
        <link>http://randomjazzband2.ran</link>
        <members>
            <drummer> Random Drummer </drummer>
            <vocal> Random Vocalist </vocal>
            <bass>Random Bassist</bass>
            <guitar>Random Guitar</guitar>
            <keys>Random keyboarder</keys>
            <other>Random otherist</other>
        </members>
    </band>
    <description>this is the event number 2, ven 1 mar</description>
</event>
</events>
```

and the following javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var day = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("day")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var weekday = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weekday")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var month = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("month")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var sideVoice = '<a class="date" onclick="showEv()">' + weekday + day + month + '</a>';
    document.getElementById("side_dates").innerHTML = sideVoice;
});

function showEv() {
    document.getElementById("event_content").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

how do i add, for each `<event>` inside the XML, a rispective `<a class="date" onclick="ShowEV()">` containing the child `<date>` and this `<date>` children's values `</a>` ?

You can see this on http://campaniajazz.altervista.org/#events

Comment: Try uncommenting the `<div id="event_content"…>` so it can get selected by `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: you're right.. that's my bad.

Comment: what about grouping the children of the date tag? there will be different `<date>` tags each of them with different children's values, i want to show all this children togheter by referring to their `<date>` parent

Comment: Do you have control over the xml? Then I would suggest changing it to `<date weekday="ven" day="15" month="feb" />`

Comment: question updated for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery for the event listeners. Also, you will need a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) to preserve the event in a variable.

```
var sideDates = $("#side_dates");
var events = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("event");
for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];

    // you might use something better to get these variables:
    var day = event.getElementsByTagName("day")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        weekday = event.getElementsByTagName("weekday")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        month = event.getElementsByTagName("month")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        description = event.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    var sideVoice = $('<a class="date">' + weekday + day + month + '</a>');
    sideVoice.on("click", makeShowFunction(description));
    sideDates.append(sideVoice);
}
function makeShowFunction(texttoshow) {
     // this closure preserves the variable "texttoshow";
     return function eventHandler(e) {
         $("#event_content").text(texttoshow);
     };
}
```

Comment: this is not showing up the #side_dates, and yes i saw the sideDates\sidedates error. Please refer to updated question and thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, fixed the syntax errors. Works now, at least from console.

Comment: shoud i put this inside the $(document).ready ? I tried both ways but still doesn't work

Comment: ok. that code solved my problem. you can see it working now. also, thommy's code will help me in better storing the values into variables. Thank you everyone, you're amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how You access the source (xml), but I made a jsFiddle & hope It helps...

http://jsfiddle.net/Nrzh8/

THE "HTML"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<hr/>Your source:<hr/>

<events>
<event>
<date>
    <weekday>ven</weekday>
    <day>15</day>
    <month>feb</month>
</date>
<place>
    <name>Blue Sound</name>
    <city>Nola</city>
    <address>Corso Italia 7</address>
</place>
<band>
    <name>Random Jazz 6some</name>
    <link>http://randomjazz6.ran</link>
    <members>
        <drummer> Random Drummer </drummer>
        <vocal> Random Vocalist </vocal>
        <bass>Random Bassist</bass>
        <guitar>Random Guitar</guitar>
        <keys>Random keyboarder</keys>
        <other>Random otherist</other>
    </members>
</band>
<description>event description here</description>
</event>    
</events>

<hr/>The result (click it!):<hr/>

<div id="side_dates"></div>
<div id="event_content"></div>
```

THE JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var xmlsrc = jQuery('event');

whole_date = xmlsrc.find('weekday').html() + ' '
           + xmlsrc.find('day').html() + ' '
           + xmlsrc.find('month').html();

var sideVoice = '<a class="date">' + whole_date + '</a>';

jQuery("#side_dates").html(sideVoice).on('click',   
  function() { jQuery('#event_content').html(xmlsrc.find('description').html());
  }
);
});
```

Comment: No, the xml is not just dropped into the HTML, that would be invalid markup. Check the source of [his site](http://campaniajazz.altervista.org/) to see where it comes from!

Comment: Yes, this was my first intention, but as the rest of his code is missing, I just showed a much shorter example. He probably can apply it to his needs.

Comment: i did not mention that data we're retrieving are from an events.xml file, inside the root directory wich was called this way `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","events.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;`

Comment: xmlsrc will be the object, no matter as like shown in the example nor passed to the var from an URL with jQuerys get() method.

Comment: ok, so just take my JS code and replace xmlsrc by your var xmlDOC.

Comment: once you have more events in the XML replace jQuery('event') by jQuery('events') and walk through it's elements using jQuerys .next(), .prev() or relative methods.

Comment: sound cool. (can't vote this, the other answer's code did solve my main issue, sorry!)